# Or on symfony findOneBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Is possible to make a request by one filed or another using the orm on symfony

```
$user_test = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:UserTest")->findOneBy([
                    'hash' => $data->user_data->hash,
                    'code' => $data->user_data->hash],
                );
```

to get something like `WHERE hash = 'foo' OR code = 'foo'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define the method in the entity UserTest repository

```
// UserTestRepository.php

public function getUserTestByHashOrCode($hash, $code){
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('hash = :hash')
        ->orWhere('code = :code')
        ->setParameter('hash', $hash)
        ->setParameter('code', $code)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

and then

```
$user_test = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:UserTest")->getUserTestByHashOrCode($data->user_data->hash, $data->user_data->hash);
```